# convert JSON to required array format in Swift3

Tags: firebase, swift3, firebase-realtime-database

We are using firebase as backend. The response we are getting from firebase is:

```
{
    "2_3" =     {
        OTI = 80;
        OTIP = 70;
        SPR2 = 40;
    };
    "2_5" =     {
        OTI = 60;
        OTIP = 70;
        SPR2 = 30;
        SPR3 = 40;
    };
    "2_8" =     {
        OTI = 20;
    };
}
```

What we want is:

```
["2_8": ["OTI": "20"], "2_3": ["SPR2": "40", "OTI": "80", "OTIP": "70"], "2_5": ["SPR2": "30", "SPR3": "40", "OTI": "60", "OTIP": "70"]]
```

How to achieve this in Swift3? Also, can we get the response from firebase in above-stated format?

Comment: You dont want the values as integers?

Comment: Those are both just different formats of printing (except for the fact that in your second format, the numbers are Strings and not Integers). So please give more context of what is it you are trying to achieve.

Comment: First of all there are no arrays involved. All collection types are dictionaries. Secondly most likely the output is exactly the format you want. `print` displays the object in an *objective-cish* dictionary representation.

Comment: Question should probably be **How to parse JSON in Swift**. And maybe also **How to serialize as JSON in Swift**.

Comment: It's going to be hard to help to see the minimal code that reproduces where you are stuck. See [How to create an MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) for more information on why this is the best way to get help on Stack Overflow for questions such as yours.

Answer (score 0):

Here's one solution; it's pretty verbose and could be shortened considerably. I added comments so you could more easily follow the logic.

There are a number of other soltutions as well.

```
var dataArray = [ [String: Any] ]()

let numbersRef = self.ref.child("numbers") //assume the parent node is called numbers
numbersRef.observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { snapshot in
    for child in snapshot.children { //iterate over each child in numbers
        let snap = child as! DataSnapshot //use the child as a snapshot
        let key = snap.key //get it's key ie. 2_3, 2_5 etc
        let value = snap.value as! [String: Any] //get it's children as a dictionary, looses ordering

        let dict = [key: value] //create a dictionary of key: value
        dataArray.append(dict) //store it
    }

    //to test
    for element in dataArray { //for each element in the dataArray
        for keyValuePair in element { //each element is a key:value pair
            let key = keyValuePair.key //get the key
            let value = keyValuePair.value //get the value
            print(key, value)
        }
    }
})
```

and the output (I just used the first two nodes)

```
2_3 ["SPR2": 40, "OTI": 80, "OTIP": 70]
2_5 ["SPR2": 30, "SPR3": 40, "OTI": 60, "OTIP": 70]
```

here's a condensed version

```
var dataArray = [ [String: Any] ]()

let numbersRef = self.ref.child("numbers") //assume the parent node is called numbers
numbersRef.observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { snapshot in
    for child in snapshot.children { //iterate over each child in numbers
        let snap = child as! DataSnapshot //tell the child it's a snapshot
        dataArray.append( [snap.key: snap.value as! [String: Any]])
    }
})
```